# How to add headers and parameters in my Code Below

Tags: swift, http-headers, nsurlsession

I have a code to fetch the contents from URL, But how do I add headers and parameters for this code below.

```
let url = NSURL(string: catURL)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
let task = session.dataTask(with: url as! URL) {
        ( data, response, error) in
        if let taskHeader = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          print(taskHeader.statusCode)
        }
        if error != nil {
            print("There is an error!!!")
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                     let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                    if let items = dictionary["course"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for item in items {
                           if let ids = item["name"] {                                    
                               print("iDS = \(ids)")
                            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create `URLRequest` with headers and use `dataTask` with this request:

**You can set parameters like this:**

```
url.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "parameterName", value: "parameterValue")
]
```

**You can set httpMethod**

```
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST" // "POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"
```

**Adding headers**

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

**You can set `jsonData` and use this data in request**

```
let json = [
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
]
```

*Dictionary to JSON:*

```
let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
```

*USAGE*

```
let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in
    // Do something...
}
task.resume()
```

**BONUS**

```
/// Print response data
if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(dataString)
}

/// Print status code
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    print(httpResponse.statusCode)
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
let url = URLComponents(string: catURL)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

url.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "parameterName", value: "parameterValue")
]

let request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["application/json": "Content-Type"]

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { ( data, response, error) in
    if let taskHeader = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(taskHeader.statusCode)
    }

    if error != nil {
        print("There is an error!!!")
        print(error)
    } else {
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                 let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as! [String:Any]
                if let items = dictionary["course"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for item in items {
                       if let ids = item["name"] {                                    
                           print("iDS = \(ids)")
                        }
```